# Why doesn't bower update bootstrap with wiredep into html?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, bower

I installed `bower install bootstrap` and then `gulp wiredep` This added bootstrap.js file in my index.html but not bootstrap.css file.

I guess this is because the `bower.json` file in `bower_components/bootstrap` folder contains this:

```
"main": [
    "less/bootstrap.less",
    "dist/js/bootstrap.js"
 ],
```

Here they don't mention `bootstrap.css` but `bootstrap.less`. Is this a bug in bootstrap? How do I fix this?

Comment: _Bower assumes that its users will use build tools (including Less/Sass/Stylus/PostCSS/etc. compilers)_. There are numerous discussions on GitHub about this [Issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16663). You'll most likely want to use a [Bower Override](https://github.com/taptapship/wiredep#bower-overrides) to resolve this or role back to [3.3.4](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.4/bower.json).

Comment: @vanburen I am using sass and even if bower assumes that then why doesn't it download sass version of bootstrap? I think bower and gulp make development more difficult and time consuming. It takes 1/3 time in development without using them.

Comment: You need to use [Bootstrap-SASS](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) then.

Comment: @vanburen I don't need bootstrap.sass for my project. I just need css. I changed bootstrap's `bower.json` and `.bower.json` files' main property from `"main": [       
   "less/bootstrap.less",
    "dist/js/bootstrap.js"
  ],` to `"main": [
    "dist/css/bootstrap.css",
    "less/bootstrap.less",
    "dist/js/bootstrap.js"
  ],` But it doesn't add bootstrap.css in index.html. Could you tell why this doesn't work.

Comment: You just stated you're using SASS two comments above and any issues you're having you should direct to the respective project maintainers.

Comment: @vanburen Yes I am using sass. But I am not using bootstrap.sass. I have finally made it work by changing `"main": [ "less/bootstrap.less", "dist/js/bootstrap.js" ]` to `"main": [ "dist/css/bootstrap.css", "dist/js/bootstrap.js" ]`.

Answer (score 0):

Fixing this is simple.

In your bower.json file add

```
  "overrides": {
    "bootstrap": {
      "main": [
        "dist/css/bootstrap.css",
        "dist/js/bootstrap.js"
      ]
    }
  }
```

Run wiredep after adding that and it should like the bootstrap.css for you too. You can of course change this to bootstrap.min.css if you like.